# Retrieve object from tapped stackpanel element

Tags: c#, uwp, stackpanel

As the title suggests, I am struggling with retrieving an element from a stackpanel list when tapping it in a simple UWP application. The stackpanel has its itemsource connected to a list of "Customers" which I am then displaying

```
            ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
            // Create a new ListView (or GridView) for the UI, add content by setting ItemsSource
            ListView customersLV = new ListView();
            customersLV.ItemsSource = customers;

            // Add the ListView to a parent container in the visual tree (that you created in the corresponding XAML file)
            customerPanel.Children.Add(customersLV);
```

The XAML-code looks like this (Added a scrollviewer for longer lists):

```
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" Margin="63,341,1043,368" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="customerPanel" Height="441" Width="394" DoubleTapped="customerPanel_DoubleTapped" ></StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

While adding and removing items from the list works great, I cannot seem to access any particular Customer-object from the listpanel when double tapping it. 
Here is my doubletap event function:

```
    private void customerPanel_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testText.Text = e.OriginalSource.ToString();
    }
```

This seems to only print a reference to the whole stackpanel and not to the specific object that I double-tapped. How can I access the tapped Customer-object if I, for example, wanted to call its ToString-method?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You haven't define the `ListView`'s `DataTemplate`, so the final result you get will be `App1.Customer`

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I am pretty new to UWP so forgive me for not quite understanding what that entails.
I was looking though [this](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) tutorial for clues, but I think it is not quite what I am after.

I simply want to store the clicked element as an object in a global variable. Am I missing something in this example?

Comment: Your link looks good, you can refer the `ListView with an ItemTemplate` part to write your own template. By the way, personly I don't suggest add `ListView` to panel through C# code, cause you also need to write template C# code. You can do this step by step following the link you posted. I will post a simple answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now I think! 
I simply put a listView within my StackPanel like this.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" Margin="63,341,1043,368" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="customerPanel" Height="441" Width="394">
                <ListView x:Name="customersLV" Tapped="listView_Tapped">
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The CS code looked like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> customers;
public MainPage()
{
      this.InitializeComponent();

      customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

      customersLV.ItemsSource = customers;
}


private void listView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
      testBox.Text = customersLV.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

This will print out the string representation of the actual Customer object in my testBox textblock :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just want to get the item value when double click the `ListViewItem`, so you just need to write a `ListView`, instead of using `ScrollViewer`, `StackPanel`, etc.
So we can write xaml code like:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" DoubleTapped="listView_DoubleTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0 10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{x:Bind Head, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="30 0 0 0" FontSize="25" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Then we define a `Customer` class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

OK, we have done half. Next we are going to create a data collection, and give it to `ListView`'s `ItemSource`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<Customer> list = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Customer p = new Customer() 
        { 
            Head = "https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/releases/2019/media/2019_rc_logo.png",
            Name = i.ToString() 
        };
        list.Add(p);
    }

    listView.ItemsSource = list;        
}
```

Final step is to complete the `DoubleTapped` event.

```
private void listView_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var customer = listView.SelectedItem as Customer;
    Debug.WriteLine(customer.Name);
}
```

Done!!!

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I really appreciate the detailed example :) 

I am not quite getting the result that I want yet though. I am trying to get the entire Customer object from clicking a list element. Not just a string attribute from it. My Customer objects are carrying a lot of different attributes which I will want to use for several things later.

Comment: `var customer = listView.SelectedItem as Customer;` is just what you want.